# Can not find module "uiohook-napi" after installation .exe in electron forge

Tags: webpack, electron, electron-packager, electron-forge

I am using electron forge with webpack and typescript, uiohook-napi is **working properly in my development platform**. Compiling the program is also working. But when I tried to run the .exe file error  ["Cannot find module 'uiohook-napi"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6vOf.png) is appearing.

module: [uiohook-napi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uiohook-napi)

#### My enviroment

uiohook-napi Version: ^1.5.3
Environment name and version: nodejs 20.9.0, electron: 29.1.5, electron-forge: ^7.3.1
Operating System and version: win32 x64

**My webpack config:**

```
import type { Configuration } from "webpack";

import { rules } from "./webpack.rules";
import { plugins } from "./webpack.plugins";

export const mainConfig: Configuration = {
  /**
   * This is the main entry point for your application, it's the first file
   * that runs in the main process.
   */
  entry: "./src/index.ts",
  // Put your normal webpack config below here
  module: {
    rules,
  },
  externals: ["electron", "uiohook-napi"],
  plugins,
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".ts", ".jsx", ".tsx", ".css", ".json"],
  },
};
```

I tried to force electron-forge to exclude uiohook-napi from the ASAR archive for it to work in packaged form. I am doing this using `packagerConfig` in my forge configuration like:

```
  packagerConfig: {
    asar: {
      unpack: "node_modules/uiohook-napi/**",
      unpackDir: "node_modules/uiohook-napi", // Exclude uiohook-napi from ASAR
    },
  },
```

note: I'm relatively new to Electron, so I apologize in advance for any beginner errors.